# Conditional Panel keeps chosen value even when hidden, how to change that?

Tags: shiny

EDIT : @stephan gave me the answer (really obvious solution that didn't even cross my mind, I feel so freaking dumb) so everything's good now ! Sorry for that

Hello everyone and sorry if a similar question has already been asked, but I am a complete beginner in shinyR and I am lost.

You'll find my code below and the link toward the app if you want to see what's happening.

I think it's overall pretty okay since almost everything works as intended.
Basically, I want to make a small webapp to help my coworker choose the proper statistic test or analysis to perform based on the data they're using (I don't know if shinyR may not be the best for such program but R is really the only computer-related language I know).

In short, the app shows a widget asking if the person want to do a Descriptive Analysis, Check for Normality or do an Inferential Analysis.
When choosing the third option, another widgets appear and ask what type of analysis (mean comparison, proportion comparisons etc...). When selecting any of the choice, other widgets appear and ask for more info.

So far everything works perfectly, but for some reason, if one does : "inferential analysis" -> "mean comparison" and THEN changes "inferential analysis" to "descriptive analysis" (so changing the very first opion), the app hide the "mean comparison" widget while keep the value set  and leave all the other widget on the screen instead of hiding them.

It's not a big deal at all but it's bothering me and I don't know how to fix it.

[Test the app to see what I mean](https://yoann-stat.shinyapps.io/Statistiques/)

```
ui <- fixedPage(
  titlePanel("Choisir son test statistique"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,selectInput("choix","Que voulez-vous faire ?", c('---',
                                                              'Analyse Descriptive'="desc",
                                                              'Vérification de Normalité'="norm",
                                                              'Test Statistique'="stat"))),
    column(3,conditionalPanel(
      condition="input.choix=='stat'",
      selectInput("type","Quel type d'analyse ?", c('---',
                                                    "Comparaison de moyenne",
                                                    "Comparaison de Pourcentages",
                                                    "Lien entre Variable")))),
    column(3,conditionalPanel(
      condition="input.type=='Comparaison de moyenne'||input.type=='Comparaison de Pourcentages'",
      selectInput("groupe","Combien de groupes ?", c('---',
                                                     "1 groupe",
                                                     "2 groupes",
                                                     ">2 groupes"))),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.type=='Lien entre Variable'",
        selectInput("variable","Quel type de variables ?", c('---',
                                                             "2 Variables Qualitatives",
                                                             "2 Variables Quantitatives",
                                                             "1 Variable Qualitative + 1 Variable Quantitative")))),
    column(3, conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.type=='Comparaison de moyenne'||input.type=='Comparaison de Pourcentages'",
      selectInput("indep", "Indépendance des données ?",c('---',
                                                                      "oui",
                                                                      "non"))),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.type=='Comparaison de moyenne'||input.type=='Comparaison de Pourcentages'",
        selectInput("param", "Normalité des données ?",c('---',
                                                                   "oui",
                                                                   "non",
                                                                   "je ne sais pas")))),
    
    mainPanel(htmlOutput("texte"))))
```

At first I thought it was due to nested Conditional Panels but from what I understand it seems like a problem with reactivity or something ?

I've read several posts and articles about observe(), eventObserve(), eventReactive() and req() but I'm honestly completely lost and don't understand any of it at all.

I've tried the show(), hide() thing from shinyjs but it didn't work (then again I may have use it wrong too)

If anyone has a solution or simple-ish explanation, that would be awesome !

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could additionally condition on `input.choix` e.g. add `input.choix === 'stat' && ...` to the conditions of the downstream panels.

Comment: @stefan so simple and obvious and yet I didn't even think of it.... I just feel dumb now xD

Thank you very much !